# Is there a continuous and satisfying a certain condition but not integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is there  a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ which satisfies
 $$
 |f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)|\leq \mathrm{const} \frac{|h|}{(\log\frac{1}{|h|})^{\beta}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,\,\, \beta \in(0, \frac{1}{2}] 
 $$ 
 for all $x,h\in [0,1]$ such that $x-h, x+h \in [0,1]$   and has bounded of variation but  $f'$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: How is this related to fourier-analysis?

Comment: The functions satisfying above inequality is called Zygmund functions (i.e, satiesfies Zygmund codition) Zygmund class have many applications investigate trigonometric series